# Reconciling two definitions of the mean value theorem in several variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

I recently saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452500/mean-value-theorem-for-several-variables) which discussed different understandings of the open set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that allows us to use the mean value theorem on several variables when $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. I looked into the mean value theorem on several variables and found two different definitions. One from the Wikipedia page which uses the gradient and another from my lectures which uses the jacobian. It seemed like the second definition is a special case when $X$ is convex and the first definition is more general. Is this an accurate way to describe the difference between this two definitions

$\mathbf{Definition}-\mathbf{1}:$ Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n $ be an open set and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $X$. Then for all  $a \in X$  and $h$ such that the segment joining $a$ to  $a + h$ is contained in $X$. Then 
there exists a point $c$ on that segment such that...

$ f(a+h) - f(a) = Df(c)\cdot h$

$\mathbf{Definition}-\mathbf{2}:$ If $b = a + h$ and $X$ is convex then 
$f(b) - f(a) = \nabla f((1 - c)a + cb) \cdot (b - a)$ where $ \nabla$ is the gradient and is the dot product.

I also I have included the tag "paramaterization" because that process helps us find the mean value theorem for several variables and I suspect that if I am missing some key point it is related to that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: define $g:\mathbb [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by $g(t)=f((1-t)a+t(a+h)),$ which makes sense in $(1)$, because the segment is contained in $X$ and in $(2)$, because $f$ is defined in a convex set. Note that $g$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$ so by the mean value theorem, there is a $c\in (0,1)$ such that  $g'(c)=g(1)-g(0)$. Can you finish by applying the multivariable chain rule, and using the definition of derivative of $f$, noting its relation to the gradient?

Comment: Thank you! I was going over the proof of using g as a single variable function and applying the mean value theoreom in one variable. I noticed also that if I swapped $b$ in definition 2 with $a +h$ that I end up with $f(a+h) - f(a) = Df(ch)(h)$. Now is this a way to convert between the two or did I make an illegal move and that $Df(ch)(h) \neq Df(c)(h)$?

Comment: Here is what I am getting: $g(1)-g(0)=g'(c)\Rightarrow f(a+h)-f(a)=Df(a+ch)\cdot h.$ Since $0<c<1,\  a+ch$ is on the line segment connecting $a$ and $a+h$. So everything looks ok. To make things look better, I guess you could set $\overline c:= a+ch$. And of course, if you sub $b-a$ for $h$, you are just redefining the variables, so nothing really changes.